# Empty map placeholder in an Istio instance

Tags: istio

I’m trying to create an Istio instance as follows:

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: accesslog
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledTemplate: logentry
  params:
    severity: '"Default"'
    timestamp: request.time
    variables:
      sourceIp: source.ip | ip("0.0.0.0")
      sourceLabels: source.labels | map[""]""
      requestPath: request.path | ""
```

I’ve tried several flavour for the empty map `map[""]""` such as `map[string]string` or `map[string]string{}{}` but none of them is accepted. The documentation I’ve read has no example of setting an empty map either. How can I declare an empty map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in the documentation: https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/expression-language/

`emptyStringMap` - `Create an empty string map`

Example use: `request.headers | emptyStringMap()`

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: accesslog
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledTemplate: logentry
  params:
    severity: '"Default"'
    timestamp: request.time
    variables:
      sourceIp: source.ip | ip("0.0.0.0")
      sourceLabels: source.labels | emptyStringMap()
      requestPath: request.path | ""
```